# Lattices in $p$-adic groups

Tags: lie-groups, ergodic-theory, lattices, arithmetic-groups

What are the examples of lattices in $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ with $n\geq 3$ or in other semisimple $p$-adic groups of higher rank?

It is known $\operatorname{SO}_n(\mathbb{Z}[1/p])$ is a lattice in $\operatorname{SO}_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ and, in general, $G(\mathbb{Z}[1/p_i,1\leq i\leq m])$ is a lattice in $G(\mathbb{R})\times \Pi_{1\leq i \leq m}G(\mathbb{Q}_{p_i})$. How can we exclude the archimedean places and consider a single prime $p$?

It is also known that irreducible lattice in $G$ are (S-)-arithmetic if the rank of $G$ is no less than 2. (See Margulis’ book [*Discrete Subgroups of Semisimple Lie Groups*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-51445-6)). But it is always assumed $S$ contains the infinite places.

A similar question: [discrete subgroups in p-adic Lie groups?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42598/discrete-subgroups-in-p-adic-lie-groups).

Comment: What is the definition of lattice?—discrete subgroup with finite covolume?  In what sense does @KeivanKarai's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/42610) to the [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42598/discrete-subgroups-in-p-adic-lie-groups) you indicated not answer your question? \\ MathJax note: please use MathJax *stars* `*stars*`, not TeX $\it fakery$ `$\it fakery$`, for italics.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: One fact is that all lattices in these groups are cocompact. We can exclude the Archimedean place when the real group is compact, i.e. when the arithmetic lattice has real rank zero.

Comment: @LSpice That answer concerns the case that the Archimedean local group is compact and can be excluded. I just want to know a single local group but not any products.

Comment: @YCor Yes, you are absolutely correct. How about the non-compact Archimedean group case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one example that I like.
Consider
$\Gamma = \{g \in SL_d\left[\sqrt{-m} /  p\right] \mid g^t \cdot g^\sigma= I \}$, where $\sigma$ is the Galois conjugate. Then this is an arithmetic lattice in $SL_d\left(\mathbb{Q}_p\right)$.

Comment: I don't understand your last assertion.

Comment: Forgot $SL_{d}$...

Comment: But $\mathrm{SL}_d(\mathbf{Z}[1/pq])$ is not a lattice in $\mathrm{SL}_d(\mathbf{Q}_p)\times\mathrm{SL}_d(\mathbf{Q}_q)$ (it is dense!). It is a lattice in $\mathrm{SL}_d(\mathbf{R})\times\mathrm{SL}_d(\mathbf{Q}_p)\times\mathrm{SL}_d(\mathbf{Q}_q)$.

Comment: @Asaf   Thank you for the example in p-adic $SL_d$. Is that arithmetic? Or what is the definition of arithmeticity in p-adic groups without a set S containing any infinite primes?

Comment: @YCor , thanks, I think I should have restricted $SL_{d}(\mathbb{Z}[1/(p_{1}\cdot p_{2})])$ to these lattices with $g^{t}\cdot g = I$ and take it in the product of $SO_{d}(\mathbb{Q}_{p_{1}})\times SO_{d}(\mathbb{Q}_{p_2})$, but for now I deleted it.

Comment: @JunYang , yes, it comes from a an arithmetic construction. The full examples starts as a suitable subgroup fo the $\mathbb{Q}$-grp $GL_{2d}(\mathbb{C})$, with $S={\infty, p}$. The thing one needs to observe is that at the infinity place, $G_{\mathbb{R}}\simeq SU_{d}(\mathbb{R})$ is compact, hence the projection of the lattice to the other factor is still a lattice.

Comment: @Asaf Thank you so much! BTW, is there any reference for this construction? It seems beyond Margulis’ book.

Comment: One recent reference is Morris' book about arithmetic groups, this construction is from section 6.3 (also 6.7,6.8). It might be in Borel's book as well, but I am not sure and I don't have the book with me.